# create JSON object from another JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I don't know if the title is the right one for what I want to do.

I have the following array of objects

```
    array([0]: {category: "10",
                question: "101"},
          [1]: {category: "10",
                question: "102"},
          [2]: {category: "20",
                question: "201"}
    );
```

And I want to group all the elements into something like this:

```
    array([0]: {category: "10", {question: "101",
                                 question: "102"}},
                category: "20", {question: "201"}});
```

I don't know if this is possible or if there's another better way to solve this problem (maybe with a two-dimensional array?) but any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Sorry for the lack of information, here is how I create my array of objects:

```
    var arr_sections = [];
    var arr_questions = [];
var jsonObj = [];
$('.ui-sortable-nostyle').each(function(){
    arr_sections.push($(this).attr("sec_id"));              
});

// create json object with pairs category - question 
$(".sortable2").each(function(i){                           
    $(this).children().each(function(j){    
        var cat = arr_sections[i];
        jsonObj.push({
            category: arr_sections[i],
            question: $(this).attr("ques_id")
        });     
    });
});
```

And got an array of objects with the following structure:

```
    [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
       category: "1052"
       question: "3701"
       __proto__: Object 
    1: Object
       category: "1053"
       question: "3702"
       __proto__: Object
    2: Object
       category: "483"
       question: "1550"
       __proto__: Object
    3: Object
       category: "483"
       question: "1548"
       __proto__: Object
    4: Object
       category: "483"
       question: "1549"
       __proto__: Object
    length: 5
```

Tried to create my new array:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++){
        temp[jsonObj[i].category] = jsonObj[i].question;
}
```

But I don't get all values:

```
    [483: "1549", 1052: "3701", 1053: "3702"]
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object, there are javascript objects and strings in JSON format, and they might look the same, but they aren't

Comment: And what you are showing us there isn't JavaScript or JSON syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification adeneo, the idea is merging an array of objects with a common structure into one single object or JSON string grouping these different values for each property

Comment: Now show us your code either as JavaScript literal object or JSON string.

Comment: You should really consider creating a simpler object, something like -> http://jsfiddle.net/T7KKw/

Comment: It's possible. How are you getting those in that array in the first place? It could be that the way you're populating the array could be modified rather than adding procedure after the fact.

Comment: ... with the extra code given, instead of this `jsonObj.push` consider   this `jsonObj[category].push`

Comment: Did you read the comments, I did post a fiddle some time ago, and I'm assuming you tested that? Just for fun, here's another one -> http://jsfiddle.net/T7KKw/1/

Comment: I did adeneo, it's exactly what I needed! I have accepted Tibos answer because it's quite self explanatory. If I can give you reputation let me know how! Many thanks again

Comment: @adeneo Hi! I think I just found where the funny term [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) comes from.
Perhaps it would better be called `JSONObjoximoron`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
var arr = [ 
  {category: "10", question: "101"},
  {category: "10", question: "102"},  
  {category: "20", question: "201"}
];
```

You want (i suppose):

```
var arrRequired = [
  {category: "10", question : ["101", "102"] },
  {category: "20", question : ["201"] }
];
```

I will give you:

```
var obj = {
  "10" : ["101", "102"],
  "20" : ["201"]
};
```

To convert what you have to what i will give you, you can do:

```
var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!result[item.category]) 
    result[item.category] = [item.question];
  else
    result[item.category].push(item.question);
});
```

To get to what you want from what i gave you, you can do:

```
var arrRequired = [];
for (var category in result){
  arrRequired.push({ 'category' : category, 'question' : result[category] });
}
```

If that is not what you want, then perhaps you should explain it better, using valid syntax.

Comment: Well, that's pretty explaining in my opinion

Answer (score -3):

Here is the answer to what you asked:

```
var object1 = JSON.parse(jsonString1);
// Do something to object1 here.
var jsonString2 = JSON.stringify(object1);
```